# ReactDOM.render alternative due to react 18 error

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

In my app I am rendering notifications using ReactDOM.render:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <NotificationsManager
    setNotify={(notifyFn) => {
      notify = notifyFn;
    }}
  />,
  containerElement
);
```

This however gives me the following error:

```
Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead. Until you switch to the new API, your app will behave as if it's running React 17. Learn more: https://reactjs.org/link/switch-to-createroot
```

If this would be the root app element I would resolve it, however this is a completely different component. Is there any alternative for this case scenario?

If I try to fix it doing this:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <NotificationsManager
    setNotify={(notifyFn) => {
      notify = notifyFn;
    }}
  />,
  containerElement
);
```

I am getting following error:

```
Warning: You passed a container to the second argument of root.render(...). You don't need to pass it again since you already passed it to create the root.
Warning: You are calling ReactDOMClient.createRoot() on a container that has already been passed to createRoot() before. Instead, call root.render() on the existing root instead if you want to update it.
```

Unfortunately calling root.render() on existing root is not possible due to the app setup.

Is there any way around this? Thank you for all your kind help.

Comment: what is `containerElement` ?

Comment: We may need more information, is `NotificationsManager` the  top-level component of your App? Are there other places that call `ReactDOM.createRoot`?

Answer (score 3):

As I understood you have a different div in your `index.html` file to render the **NotificationManager** notifications. In other words you have the following structure:

```
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="notification-manager"></div>
  </body>
```

If I'm right you can do the following:

- Index.jsx:

```
const container = document.getElementById('root'),
  root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

- Create a **Portal** component which will inject the required HTML element into the DOM as a sibling of your **root div**, if it doesn't exist

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';

function createWrapperAndAppendToBody(wrapper, wrapperElementId) {
  const wrapperElement = document.createElement(wrapper);
  wrapperElement.setAttribute('id', wrapperElementId);
  document.body.appendChild(wrapperElement);
  return wrapperElement;
}

const Portal = ({ children, wrapperElement, wrapperElementId }) => {
  const [wrapper, setWrapper] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let element = document.getElementById(wrapperElementId);
    // if element is not found with wrapperElementId or wrapperElementId is not provided,
    // create and append to body
    if (!element) {
      element = createWrapperAndAppendToBody(wrapperElement, wrapperElementId);
    }
    setWrapper(element);
  }, [wrapperElementId, wrapperElement]);

  // wrapper state will be null on the first render.
  if (wrapper === null) return null;

  return createPortal(children, wrapper);
};

export default Portal;
```

- Utilize the portal component in your NotificationManger:

```
const NotificationsManager = ({ setNotify }) => {
  //your logic

  return (
    <Portal wrapperElement="div" wrapperElementId="notification-manager">
      {/*your jsx*/}
    </Portal>
  );
};

export default NotificationsManager;
```

- Use the **NotificationManger** in your App.jsx:

```
const App = () => (
  <div className='app'>
    <NotificationsManager
      setNotify={(notifyFn) => {
        notify = notifyFn;
      }}
    />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: That's useful example, thnx

Answer (score -1):

The following:

```js
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <NotificationsManager
    setNotify={(notifyFn) => {
      notify = notifyFn;
    }}
  />,
  containerElement
);
```

should be:

```js
// assuming that you had previously declared the root element:
const containerElement = document.getElementById("root");
//

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(containerElement);
root.render(
  <NotificationsManager
    setNotify={(notifyFn) => {
      notify = notifyFn;
    }}
  />
);
```

As the error message says:

> You don't need to pass it again since you already passed it to create the root.

So you needn't pass it again. Your question mentions `containerElement`, but I'm assuming you've already created that variable with the value: `document.getElementById("root")`

Comment: Thank you for taking a time to reply. I did as you suggested. I am however getting following error: ```react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: You are calling ReactDOMClient.createRoot() on a container that has already been passed to createRoot() before. Instead, call root.render() on the existing root instead if you want to update it.```

Comment: @xyz83242 in that case it sounds like you have too many files that create the React “root” with ReactDOM, you may need to search the whole of your project and update the question with your findings